# snmp-server trap-source using pysnmp

Tags: python, pysnmp

I'm relatively new to pysnmp. My current requirement is to support trap source for snmp traps. I am trying to understand how I can support this with pysnmp ntforg.NotificationOriginator construct.

My current code snippet for sending out traps is as follows:

```
varBinds = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'coldStart')
    trapVarBinds = trapAgent.VarBinds(varBinds,'','')
    trapPdu = rfc1902.NotificationType(
                varBinds
            ).resolveWithMib(self.mibViewController)        
    SendTrap(trapAgent.TrapData(trapPdu,trapVarBinds))

 def SendTrap(self,trapData):
    for server in trapServer:  #list of trapServer config info
        data = trapServer[server]
        print 'Trap server:%s'%(data,)
        sendRequestHandle = ntforg.NotificationOriginator(snmpContext).sendVarBinds(
        snmpEngine,
        data.Name,
        #None,'',
        snmpContext.contextEngineId,'',
        trapData.trapPdu
        )
```

Any insights/advice on how to support for trap source here would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what is trap source? Here's [an example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html#snmpv2c-trap-via-notification-type) or SNMP trap sender.

Comment: trap source is a way to configure the source (ip/interface) of the trap sender 
 snmp-server trap-source:
Specifies the interface (and hence the corresponding IP address) that an SNMP trap should originate from.

Answer (score 0):

refer [Notification Originator](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/ntforg/trap-v1-from-specific-address.html)

you can specify source IP and port like below

```
from pysnmp.entity import config
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp

config.addSocketTransport(
snmpEngine,
udp.domainName,
udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode(iface=('127.0.0.1', 1024))
)
```